# Postgresql return number of replies for each comment

Tags: postgresql, subquery

I have a comments table that looks like:

```
CREATE TABLE comments (
    comment_id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    user_id VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    username VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    content VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    created_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT now(),
    post_id VARCHAR(255) references posts(post_id),
    reply_to INT,
);
```

For each comment, I'm trying to select the number of replies. A comment that is a reply will have a `reply_to` column that references the `comment_id` the reply is in response too.

I'm trying to select all column that are in response to a post, however I also want to select the number of replies each of those comments have.

This is the query:

```
SELECT comment_id, username, content, 
( 
 SELECT COUNT(comments.*) FROM comments 
 JOIN comments comments1 on comments.comment_id = comments1.reply_to
)
as replies FROM comments WHERE post_id = 'uuid';
```

The query returns:

| comment_id | username | content | replies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | username1 | comment content | 1 |
| 3 | username2 | comment content | 1 |

The problem is that it returns both comments have a reply count of 1 even though I have only 1 record that has a `reply_to` column of 3.

Comment: How deeply nested can replies go? Is it possible for a comment to have a reply which in turn will have a reply? Or can a comment have a reply but it is not possible to reply to that reply?

If replies can be deeply nested, should the reply count for a comment only count its  immediate children or should it also count all of its descendents?

Comment: Replies can only go 1 level deep. An example would be instagram or youtube comments, you can reply to the post but not to comments of that post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Why your solution does not work**

The subquery you use in your SELECT clause is inner joining ALL comments with ALL of their replies and then doing a count on ALL of the resultant rows in the resultant table. Note you are using an inner join in your example (JOIN is shorthand for INNER JOIN) so if a comment does not have any replies it is not included in the resultant table. So the count is  of ALL the comments which have at least one reply.

```
( 
 -- you are counting ***ALL** the comments in your table inner joined onto their replies.
 SELECT COUNT(comments.*) FROM comments 
 JOIN comments comments1 on comments.comment_id = comments1.reply_to
)
```

But you want the count to be scoped to each comment so that it's the count of only their replies, not the entire table.

**The solution**

Assuming replies can only go one level deep then I believe you can either use a lateral join or a common table expression using a window function.

Here is how to solve it with lateral joins. If I have time later I'll update my answer with a window function approach. I think however on average, lateral joins are more performant than a window function approach though it may depend on your data.

```
create temporary table comments (
    id serial primary key,
  post_id int,
  reply_to_id int, 
  body varchar
);

-- the body for each comment illustrates the comment hierarchy for a post
-- POST.PARENT_COMMENT.REPLY. E.g. 1.1.1  means this comment is a reply to the first comment for the first post.
insert into comments (post_id, reply_to_id, body) values
(1, null, '1.1'),
(1, 1, '1.1.1'),
(1, 1, '1.1.2'),
(1, null, '1.2'),
(2, null, '2.1'),
(2, 5, '2.1.1');

-- Lets look at the comments with their replies 
select comments.*, replies.* from comments
left outer join comments as replies on comments.id = replies.reply_to_id
order by comments.post_id, replies.reply_to_id ASC;

/*
|             COMMENT               |             REPLY                  |
 id | post_id | reply_to_id | body  | id | post_id | reply_to_id | body
----+---------+-------------+-------+----+---------+-------------+-------
  1 |       1 |             | 1.1   |  3 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.2
  1 |       1 |             | 1.1   |  2 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.1
  3 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.2 |    |         |             |
  2 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.1 |    |         |             |
  4 |       1 |             | 1.2   |    |         |             |
  5 |       2 |             | 2.1   |  6 |       2 |           5 | 2.1.1
  6 |       2 |           5 | 2.1.1 |    |         |             |
*/

--- now lets get the reply count 
select comments.*, r.reply_count from comments
left join lateral (
        select count(replies.id) as reply_count from comments as replies
  where comments.id = replies.reply_to_id
) as r on true
order by comments.post_id ASC;

/*
 id | post_id | reply_to_id | body  | reply_count
----+---------+-------------+-------+-------------
  1 |       1 |             | 1.1   |           2
  2 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.1 |           0
  3 |       1 |           1 | 1.1.2 |           0
  4 |       1 |             | 1.2   |           0
  5 |       2 |             | 2.1   |           1
  6 |       2 |           5 | 2.1.1 |           0
*/
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your response. I'm a bit confused on how `join lateral` is working where. A SO answer says `Subqueries appearing in FROM can be preceded by the key word LATERAL. This allows them to reference columns provided by preceding FROM items`. Are you using a lateral join to compare the `comments.id and reply_to_id` and to return them only if they match?

Comment: Yes that is correct. Using a lateral lets me reference any column from any of the tables declared in the outer FROM clause (in this case comments). So in the lateral clause I can say "for this given comment row, please join all the other comments whose reply_to_id matches the comment row's id.".

Comment: I also updated my answer to explain why your original solution will not work.